Does including commercial links (to the poster's benefit) explicitly violate Stack Exchange rules?
Maybe I should divide the question into two separate ones, but I'm wondering if making commercial use of Stack Exchange violates any rules. Specifically,

If I put affiliate Amazon links in my answers, is it a violation of anything stated in user agreement (or the like)?

If I create an account on Patreon or Buy Me a Coffee or that kind of thing, and start subscription for accepting questions (like, urging the user to post questions on SE and guarantee answering there), is it a violation of anything?


I'm aware of the following and similar questions already asked, but those seem to be only opinions. I'm looking for  which part of user agreement (or anything that follows from creating an account on SE) doing the above conflicts with.

Affiliate links (Amazon and others)

(Not that I seriously think of doing it or that it's going to work.)

FYI, the top answer to the question you linked was written by Stack Exchange's main leader at the time, Jeff Atwood, and therefore his posting that answer at the time was effectively enacting it as policy.

Rules and ToS aside, this will be reported, and most likely nuked, as spam - by individual users. The author might then appeal to the company, but I doubt they'll undelete or do anything against the users who flagged spam.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda As long as links are relevant and unless they are explicitly prohibited, I don't think it's fair to call it a spam.

Fair or not fair, I'd call it spam and flag as such, unless told otherwise by a staff member of SE or moderator.

For questions like this, it is usually best not to accept the answer you wish to be true – at least, not until it's had some time as the top-rated answer.

@wizzwizz4 I'm not particularly wishing anything. The answer I accepted addressed the points that are relevant to the scenario I had in mind. That's all. Inauthenticity stuff the other answers cite do not seem to fit the scenario (in my comment to cocomac's answer).


I'm wondering if making commercial use of Stack Exchange violates any rules.

Not inherently. If you abide by the terms of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license, you're even allowed to sell other people's work without ever once contributing to the Stack Exchange library. (But please don't. That is not a good way to make friends.)


If I put affiliate Amazon links in my answers,

This is a textbook example of spamming, which is not allowed. Though, interestingly, those links wouldn't do anything: the Stack Exchange software still handles Amazon links specially, effectively stripping the affiliation.


If I create an account on Patreon or Buy Me a Coffee or that kind of thing, and start subscription for […] guarantee answering [a question], is it a violation of anything?

If you:

vet the questions before making promises, to ensure that they're suitable for the site,

or, walk your client through the process of asking a good question, assisting as necessary, and abandon the question if it can't be made suitable,
or, edit your client's question to make it suitable, before answering;


provide an answer that meets the site's standards; and
only upvote the question if it's especially good,

or, to be safe, refrain from upvoting the question at all;



then no, this is not a violation of anything. It abides by the letter and the spirit of the inauthentic usage policy, which is an accurate reflection of the consensus.
However, failing any one of these conditions would be a serious breach of the rules, and – owing to the for-profit nature of the activity – not one I would expect to be handled kindly. Network moderators aren't allowed to make concrete threats (something something "case-by-case basis"), but… I wouldn't be inclined to be lenient with suspensions, in the circumstances you describe.
The Help Center contains some friendly advice on how to not be a spammer. The second half is quite relevant to your example, so please keep it in mind.

If the only reason you're here is to sell something or drive traffic to [a] site, then please avoid posting answers.


For both of your questions, below are just the first things which come to mind which the conduct you propose would violate within the Terms of Service, Acceptable Use Policy, and Code of Conduct. There may be additional sections of those agreements and policies which would be violated. I haven't gone through and, yet again, re-read all of those policies just to search for what you're interested in. There are definitely additional rules/policies which would be violated, but I don't see any use in spending the time to go though and identify the specific section of everything which the proposed conduct violates.
You should read those policies, given that you are wondering what they say and are considering conduct which isn't "normal", or which is specifically intended to be to your financial benefit. In general, you should make yourself aware of the restrictions under which you operate (e.g., laws and the contracts you've agreed to), particularly when you're trying to make money. Looking into, explaining, and giving advice on such things, and, in particular, how they relate to your specific circumstances is one of the primary things that lawyers do. If you are unwilling or unable to spend the time to do so for yourself or feel things are too complex, then your best bet is to hire a lawyer, especially when you start thinking "Hmmm... maybe I can try this cool hack to make money. I wonder if it's legitimate." I'm reminded of xkcd #1494: Insurance:

Your first question


If I put affiliate amazon links in my answers, is it a violation of anything stated in user agreement (or the like)?


This would be a violation of the Acceptable Use Policy, which says:

Spam
You may not post content for the purpose of affiliated marketing (e.g., to promote a product, service, or similar in a way that is unsolicited or lacks disclosure of affiliation), or use deceptive means to generate revenue or traffic. Posting irrelevant content, non-meaningful content, or other types of content that may reasonably be interpreted as spam per individual site policies, is also prohibited.

Your second question


If I create an account on Patreon or Buy Me a Coffee or that kind of thing, and start subscription for accepting questions (like, urging the user to post questions on SE and guarantee answering there), is it a violation of anything?


Interpreting your second question as: can I be paid to answer?
If your second question could be rephrased as:

Can I, completely off of Stack Exchange, solicit people to pay me in real money to post my honest, best attempt at answering a question they specify on Stack Exchange without any commitment on anybody's part to vote on any question, answer, or comment, nor offer a bounty to the answer, nor approve an edit, nor accept the answer, nor promote the question or answer, nor promote any product, service, etc. within the answer, etc. (i.e., can I be paid strictly to answer questions on Stack Exchange)?

The answer to that is: I'm unaware of any agreement, rule, or policy which prohibits that, as long as all other all other agreements, rules, and policies are being obeyed.
In fact, I am aware of companies which pay employees and/or contractors to answer questions on Stack Overflow. While there have been a variety of problems associated with that being done (e.g., excessive promotion of products or services, or violations of other rules or policies), the basic concept of being paid to answer a specified question, or group of questions, has generally been considered to not violate any rules or policies.
You need to be very careful in what happens other than strictly you answering the question.
You need to be very careful not to violate other rules or policies, or even having the potential appearance of having violated them.
It would be a good idea to avoid voting on the questions, even if you think they are acceptable, as that might be seen as being paid to vote on the question. If you only vote on such a question when you consider that its quality is exceptional, that might be reasonable.
There are lots of potential things that might be part of what you do that is associated with answering which could be interpreted as violating various rules and policies, particularly if you do it on a regular basis and/or for multiple questions by the same customer/client and/or about the same products/technology/thing/service/etc.
You definitely need to be concerned about not doing things which would be a violation of the Code of Conduct: Inauthentic usage policy, which says:

Furthermore, we do not allow what we define as inauthentic usage of our systems, such as:

Artificially boosting the popularity/score of content and/or users.

…

Patterns of voting that appear to be solely based on rewarding or punishing specific users in a targeted manner or that appear to be cast with disregard to the content being voted on.

…

Coordinating inauthentic behavior, including, but not limited to, through the use of fake accounts.


Then there are also things like: you should make sure that the question is actually on-topic for the site and that it's not low quality.

Note: I am not a lawyer. This is not legal advice.

there's an XKCD for everything innit? :D

xkcd 1494 explained

Not to mention that posting Amazon affiliate links is a violation of Amazon's TOS: You aren't allowed to post Affiliate links on a site you don't own.  Here's an answer on User Experience Meta that targets those TOS sections: https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1651/34258


What Jeff Atwood said there seems to be mostly policy, and I'd agree. Don't use affiliate links. If it's a one-off mistake, editing it out and leaving a comment might be good enough. But if it's a pattern, that's likely to qualify as spam. Whether it get's edited out or spam nuked depends, but still don’t do it. "You may not post content for the purpose of affiliated marketing" from the AuP seems to qualify here.
Including Amazon links isn't inherently bad (but avoid relying on the links working!), but just don't make it an affiliate link. This on Acedemia SE is worth reading. Not the same, but related.
Yes, it is. It will probably violate the "don’t answer bad questions" guidance. It also could likely be voting fraud if it was payment for accepted answers. The disruptive use of tooling policy would apply, and it might count as inappropriate use of sock puppet accounts depending on what you did. Inauthenticity of you gaining badges could also be an issue.
I can't think of more violations off the top of my head, but it's something I'd absolutely consider contacting SE about if someone was doing this, especially if it seemed like it was attracting bad questions or becoming voting fraud.


Re 2: Not sure what a bad question is, but assume that all questions are totally on-topic on the SE. Except I'm paid by the questioner, what I'd be doing is completely the same otherwise. This does not look to me 'inauthentically collecting badges' - badges are gained from (ideally) properly answering proper questions.

@sundowner For your first point, I meant off-topic or otherwise not meeting standards (grammar, formatting, code as images, etc.). For the second, I didn't mean it automatically is. Rather, it might turn into that. What you described would, IMO, be pretty situation-specific depending on a number of factors, so saying exactly what rules would apply is hard.
